# Как проверить что блок существует в handlebars?

Tags: node.js, handlebars

Допустим объявил такой блок, но не зарегистрировал его. А он должен присутствовать. В итоге я никак не узнаю что его нет. А должна быть ошибка компиляции.

```
{{#"МОЙ БЛОК"}}
 123
{{/"МОЙ БЛОК"}}
```